# Which chart (tool) I can use for drawing "cloud points" scatter with strength ties between them all?

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, scatter-plot

I have big dataset with 200 items. For each math correlation value with others. Matrix 200x200.
Something like that:

```
item item correl

   1    1      1
   2    1   0.58
   3    1   0.95
   4    1  -0.05
   1    2   0.58
   2    2      1
   3    2   0.42
   4    2  -0.20
   1    3   0.95
   2    3   0.42
   3    3      1
   4    3   0.09
   1    4  -0.05
   2    4  -0.20
   3    4   0.09
   4    4      1
```

Or without duplicates:

```
item item correl

   1    2   0.58
   2    3   0.42
   3    4   0.09
   4    1  -0.05
   1    3   0.95
   2    4  -0.20
```

(Similar mechanism uses full text search: docs->doc->words, where we count doc weigth per word and further sort docs by words in query)

I need to draw network scatter where each point will be related by tie strength with each other. Something like gravity where points groups by correlation value

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQiip.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knqSe.png)

Prefer for interactions: select, zoom, sort, filter, search etc
You know tool something like this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for D3.js

[D3](https://d3js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118
- https://d3js.org/